# vb.net math issue - Getting position in percent of mouse location

Tags: vb.net, math, location, percentage

I have a picturebox 617 pixels long, located 123 pixels to the right of the control left edge.

it is being used with another picturebox to create a progressbar.
The actual use is to be a 'seeker' in an audio player.

I'm trying to implement seeking based on where i click on the picturebox, but can't quite understand how to set the seek position (in milliseconds) to the location the user would click.

I imaging if i could get the value of the percentage of the click mouse click location relevant to the picturebox's width i could work from there - but i can't figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I got the mouse position relative to the control using `picturebox.PointToClient(MousePosition).x`.

Got percent by multiplying by 100, then dividing by the the picturebox width.

I then got the position in milliseconds by multiplying the song time (in seconds) by 1000, then multiplying that by the percentage divided by 10.

`seeker.ms = (songlength * 100) * (percent / 10)`